# How can I reformat a time string in multiple files?

Tags: text-processing

I have files which has the following lines

```
15.07.2015 12:24:47; +107.117 ; +106.925 ; +17.179 ; +102.099 ; +16.151
```

The first is the time stamp in a non standard format, how can I replace it inline to have the following format

```
2015-07-15 12:24:47; +107.117 ; +106.925 ; +17.179 ; +102.099 ; +16.151
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use SED with an appropriate pattern along the lines of
 `s#([0-9]{2})\.([0-9]{2})\.([0-9]{4})#\3-\2-\1#`
 This could be made more robust by matching the start of line anchor too if required.

Comment: I tried your solution `sed -i 's#([0-9]{2})\.([0-9]{2})\.([0-9]{4})#\3-\2-\1#' *.txt` but I am getting the following error: sed: -e expression #1, char 46: invalid reference \3 on `s' command's RHS

Comment: You may need to use an additional command  line switch (maybe -E?) to allow 'Extended' regular expressions rather than just 'Basic' regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way using a Perl one-liner...

```
$ perl -i -ne 's/^(\d{2})\.(\d{2})\.(\d{4})/$3-$2-$1/; print' in.txt
$ cat in.txt    
2015-07-15 12:24:47; +107.117 ; +106.925 ; +17.179 ; +102.099 ; +16.151
```